# sed pad a string containing a number with 0 if less than 10

Tags: sed

I have a few strings:

```
4/1
4/2
4/40
```

..and would like to use sed to pad the strings with numbers less than 10 with a 0 so the output would look like:

```
4/01
4/02
4/40
```

I'm having problems crafting a sed statement to this. Can you please help?

This is what I have so far, I'm not sure what to do where I have the '???'

```
sed 's#\/[0-9]#\/0???#g' myfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were quite close:

```
$ sed -r 's#/([0-9])$#/0\1#' a
4/01
4/02
4/40
```

Just look for the end of line `$` and catch the block within `()` to print it back with `\1`. Also, no need to `g`, because it will happen just once per line. Finally, there is no need to escape `/`, because you were using the separator `#` instead.

Comment: change all `\/` -> `/`, that is why you used `#` right? :-)

Comment: Pretty true, @Kent , I based my solution on OP's sample and I did not notice I could remove them. Thanks!